# Pull in content from page defined as static front page

Tags: frontpage

I am trying to pull in `<?php the_content(); ?>` for the page I have defined as the static front page in WordPress's back-end but can't figure out how to target it and pull it in.

Comment: If you want to define a template for the static frontpage you selected under settings. You can create a file called front-page.php. If you just need the_content(), you can follow @Sisir instructions below.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for a solid hour and never came across this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the static front page saved as an option name `page_on_front`. You can get it as

`$front_page_id = get_option('page_on_front');`

Once you have it call `get_post_field()`.

`$content = get_post_field('post_content', $front_page_id );`